# Quasiconformal maps take null sets to null sets

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory, quasiconformal-maps

Let $f:U\rightarrow V$ be some quasiconformal map in the plane. I want to show that the formula
$$\mathrm{area}(f(E)) = \int_{E}|f_z|^2-|f_{\bar{z}}|^2\mathrm{d}x\, \mathrm{d}y$$
is valid.

There are several proofs on this based on Green's formula, for instance in [Ahlfors book](https://bookstore.ams.org/ulect-38) but I am interested in proving this without the use of line integrals. There are some notes by Chris Bishop [which can be found here](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Ebishop/classes/math627.S18/QC.pdf) where he proves this result without the use of Green's formula.

**The following is from Corollary 5.6 on p. 101 in Bishops notes.**  There are some parts of the proofs that I don't understand and would like help unraveling.

1. The procedure is the following. We fix a rectangle $Q$ and take a sequence $f_n$ obtained from $f$ via convolution with bump functions. The $f_n$ then converges uniformly to $f$. In the end he has the following statement: [image]
   This is what I have trouble understanding. Just because $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ is it necessarily so that if $K$ is a compact subset of the interior of $Q$ that $f_n(Q)$ eventually contains $f(K)$? I just don't see why this should be true. My thought goes to space filling curves where we can find sequences $f_n:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\mathrm{area}(f_n[0,1]) = 0$ however $f([0,1]) = [0,1]\times [0,1]$.  Of course in this example the domain is not in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the map $f$ is not 1-1 however I think this requires some additional argument?
2. Why does he need that the Jacobian is $L^p$ for some $p>1$? He only seem to use that $f_z$ and $f_{\bar{z}}$ are in $L^2$ when he applies the Hardy little maximal theorem.

I will be thankful for any help on this!

Comment: Hint: Use the ACL property of qc maps.

Comment: But that would be for the Green's theorem solution. I'm wondering about the specific proof by Bishop which is linked

Comment: I see. Then for part 1 one needs to invoke a degree argument using the fact that $f$ is a homeomorphism. For the 2nd part, I have no idea. Maybe it is used later on.

Comment: For the 1st part: Could you give some details on the degree argument? What kind of theorem could be used?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\Omega$ is a relatively compact domain in ${\mathbb R}^n$ and
$f: cl\Omega\to {\mathbb R}^n$ is a continuous map. Then for $y\notin f(\partial \Omega)$  one defines the *degree* of $f$ at $y$, $deg(f; y)$, see for instance, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_continuous_mapping). The degree is stable under proper homotopy of maps. In particular, suppose that
you have a sequence of maps $f_k: cl\Omega\to {\mathbb R}^n$ converging uniformly to $f: cl\Omega\to {\mathbb R}^n$. Then, assuming that $deg(f; y)$ is defined, we have
$$
deg(f; y)= deg(f_k; y)
$$
for all large $k$. In particular, if $f$ is an orientation-preserving  homeomorphism to its image, then for $y\in f(\Omega)$, $deg(f; y)=+1$. Thus, for all large $k$, $deg(f_k; y)=1$, hence, $y\in f_k(\Omega)$.